# Selenium Python - how to get deeply nested element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am exploring Selenium Python and trying to grab a name property from Linkedin page in order to get its index later.

This is the HTML:

[image]

Here is how I try to do it:

```
all_span = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "span")

all_span = [s for s in all_span if s.get_attribute("aria-hidden") == "true"]

counter = 1
for i in all_span:
    print(counter)
    print(i.text)
    counter += 1
```

The problem is there are other spans on the same page that also have **aria-hidden=true** attribute, but not relevant and that messes up the index.

So I need to reach that span that contains name from one of its its parent divs but I don't know how.
Looking at documentation here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html# I cant seem to find how to target deeply neseted elements.

I need to get the name that is in span element.

The [link](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?network=%5B%22F%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&page=2&sid=n4N)

Comment: There are a lot of `span` elements on such page. Can you share a **link**, not a picture to some specific page and clarify what elements do you want to get there?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use xpath.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use xpath. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath

Let's say you have this:

```html
<div id="this-div-contains-the-span-i-want">
  <span aria-hidden="true">
  <!--
  ...
  //-->
  </span>
</div>
```

Then, using xpath:

```
xpath = "//div[@id='this-div-contains-the-span-i-want']/span[@aria-hidden='true']"
span_i_want = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

So, in your example, you could use:

```
xpath = "//a[@class='app-aware-link']/span[@dir='ltr']/span[@aria-hidden='true']"
span_i_want = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
print(span_i_want.text)
```

No typos but

```
print(span_i_want) - returns [] empty array
```

Comment: Can I chain it like "//div1/div2/span1/span2"?  Can I also shorten"this-div-contains-the-span-i-want" ?

Comment: you have to identify the div somehow, in the snippet, i used the div id. You can chain multiple divs if you want to, but you have to identify all of them, e.g. by id/class, etc.

Comment: There are no ids in this case. Only class names with many classes in each string as you can see in the picture.  It is possible to do something like "this-class-*" ?

Comment: i added the xpath for your example, hope I did not make a typo

Comment: No typos but

    print(span_i_want) - returns [] empty array